# Вращение предмета

Tags: jquery, flash, javascript

Добрый день. Мне нужно задать вращение предмета. Есть (допустим) слиток золота и мне нужно, чтобы он вращался. Можно ли это реализовать с помощью JavaScript или только Flash (a если только flash, сложно ли будет это реализовать). И может подскажете, с чего начать.

Comment: Можно с помощью gif

Comment: Просто желательно использовать одну из этих технологий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тогда, думаю, самым простым будет сделать картинку со всеми кадрами вращающейся фигуры выстроенными в столбик. Сделать блок `div`. Задать ему фиксированный размер одного кадра. Картинку назначить фоном для этого блока. И, по таймеру, менять позицию фона. Этот прием называется "CSS спрайты". Поищите в поисковых системах.

Comment: Ужас. А анимированный gif не проще?

Comment: Проще, но задача топикстартера сделать или на JavaScript или на Flash.

Comment: спасибо, этот вариат мне подходит) теперь хоть знаю в какую сторону двигаться

Answer (score 1):

Вращать картинку или блок кроссбраузерно не тривиальная задача. Если вам надо вращать картинку, то можно использовать svg, как показано на [этом примере](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html), однако это хорошо работает только в нормальных браузерах, например в ие7 оно немного поддергивается при вращении.

Можно использовать аякс и поворот картинки на сервере, вы посылаете запрос, где указываете картинку и в какую сторону повернуть, сервер поворачивает картинку и возвращает вам в ответе (так вроде сейчас вконтакте работает). Ну и не кроссбраузерно с помощью [css3](http://www.css3demos.rusdigi.org/spining_css.html)

Comment: На счет аякса - это вы погорячились. Где-то читал что даже запрос без какой-либо обработки по времени занимает 120ms. А на генерацию кадра сервером тоже нужно время. Представляю себе такую анимацию :).

В таком варианте, вначале как минимум нужно закешировать все кадры, а уже потом выводить по таймеру.

Comment: на аяксе конечно не анимацию делать, просто поворот на бок на 90 градусов

Comment: Если вращать в плоскости, то лучше уж [на JavaScript][1].

  [1]: http://romka.eu/blog/jquery-image-rotate

Comment: На счет аякса — какой же здесь бред написан